# Why doesn't the destructor get called on objects you are returning?

Tags: c++

So as I understand it you can return objects in C++ by returning pointers to them.  But I was under the impression that once a function is finished running, the destructor gets called on all the objects.  Why doesn't the destructor get called on the object you're returning?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only the destructors of objects with *automatic storage duration* are called when those objects leave their scope (not just a function, but any scope: braces, `for`-statements, even single-line expressions).

On the other hand, objects of *static* storage duration are only destroyed at program exit, and objects of *dynamic* storage duration (i.e. those created with a `new` operator) only get destroyed manually on *your* request.

When you return a pointer in the way you describe, then almost surely that pointer points to a dynamically created object, and thus it is the responsibility of the recipient of the pointer to see to it that the object is eventually cleaned up. This is the great disadvantage of naked pointers: They do not convey any implicit ownership statement, and you have to provide the information about who's responsible for the dynamic object manually outside the code.

Answer (score 1):

The destructor for an object you created with `new` doesn't get called until you `delete` the pointer.

To make sure you don't forget to delete the pointer, try using smart pointers such as `std::shared_ptr` or `std::unique_ptr`.

If your compiler isn't new enough to include smart pointers, you can find some from [Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/smart_ptr/smart_ptr.htm).

Answer (score 1):

When you return the reference to the object it is no longer scoped to the function and therefore does not die with the function (ie the pointer to the object does not get deleted).

Answer (score 1):

That would only happen if you wrote code incorrectly. For example:

```
Foo* MyFunction()
{
    Foo foo(2);
    return &foo;
} // foo is implicitly destroyed as we return
```

This is broken. I take the address of `foo`, but it is also destroyed because it goes out of scope. This is fine:

```
Foo* MyFunction()
{
    Foo* j=new Foo(2);
    return j;
} // j is implicitly destroyed as we return
```

This is fine. While `j` is destroyed because it goes out of scope, the value that I returned is still the address of the `Foo` I created. The `foo` that I allocated will not be destroyed because it doesn't go out of scope.

Comment: You might want to mention `static Foo foo(2); return &foo;` scenario.

Comment: Why doesn't the Foo object go out of scope in the second example?

Comment: @badatmath: The `Foo*` object (`j`) goes out of scope (and is destroyed because it has automatic storage duration), but the `Foo` created by `new Foo(2)` has dynamic storage duration (and is only destroyed when you explicitly destroy it (with `delete`)). The `Foo` created by `new Foo(2)` is never really in a scope (it lives out in the ether on the free store), so it can't go out of scope.

Comment: @badatmath: What name would go out of scope? The only name created inside the scope of the function is `f`.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: but I thought the object was created inside the scope too?  Or does the destructor thing only apply to variables that were actually declared (like j as opposed to the object it points to)?

Comment: @badatmath: When an object is created does not determine its scope. *How* it is created does.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways of allocating objects: the stack and the heap.

1) Objects are created on the *heap* with the `new` keyword.  These objects are not destroyed until they are `delete`d.

2) Other objects exist on the *stack* - no `new`, no `delete`.  These objects are destroyed when they go out of scope.  If you return a pointer to one of these objects (by taking the address of a stack-allocated object, the pointer will be invalid once the object has gone out of scope.

Answer (score -1):

C++ (outside of .net) does not delete an object until you tell it to.